# How to get the old value of variable stored in a new variable when the variable changes in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have this code below which adds a class to the respective element it needed to add.

```
const hash = window.location.hash;

if (hash) {
  const id = symbolRemover(hash) + "__list";
  document.getElementById(id).classList.add("active");
}
```

---

*The problem is it adds the class every time the `hash` changes. But as the `hash` changes the `active` class which was added before remains there, and every time the `hash` changes it adds but I want to remove the class of `active` from it as the `hash` changes. So there is only one unique element with the class of `active`.*

I am thinking that somehow we save the `id` in another variable whenever the hash changes. Somewhat like:

```
const oldId = id;
// I know this does not work.
```

*I am new to React so don't know much about it. Any help will be appreciated.*

*Thanks.*

Comment: That code doesn't look like React code. Normally in React you wouldn't use `classList`, you'd just change what you're rendering to the `className` property.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I actually don't know how to do so it in `react` so I went the normal `js` way ^_____^

Answer (score -1):

You are right. When we think logically you need to keep the old element. Like this;

```
let prevElement;
const hash = window.location.hash;

if (hash) {
  if (prevElement) {
    prevElement.classList.remove("active");
  }

  const id = symbolRemover(hash) + "__list";
  const element = document.getElementById(id);
  element.classList.add("active");
  prevElement = element;
}
```

But you should make some null check here for example

what if element is undefined? then you get an error, so you can update like this:

```
  const element = document.getElementById(id);

  if (element) {
    ...
  }
```

This answer it may not be a perfectly matched answer. but I hope you got the idea